# Link Javascript file with wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I am struggling with finishing a basic plugin I created.

I have a plugin folder with the following structure:

```
Folder_name: Booking
booking.php
js - script.js
css - style.css
js and css are sub folders in the Booking folder.
```

I have the following function in the booking.php file:

```
function sc_booking_process() {
    return 'html content which uses divs which connect to js and css files';
}
 add_shortcode('cinema-booking', 'sc_booking_process');
?>
```

The booking.php needs to link to the javascript and css files to work properly but no matter what method I do it wont work.

I have tried putting the following before the above function but they still aren't linked to it:

```
function my_scripts_and_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-css', 'css/style.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-js', 'js/script.js', array('jquery'), '20200110' );       
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_css' );
```

Any advise would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function my_scripts_and_css() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/css/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '20200110' );       

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_css' );
```

You call wrong dir for css and js, please try this one! hope it will work for you

Comment: Thank you for replying. It still is not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function my_scripts_and_css() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-css', plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-js', plugins_url( '/js/script.js',__FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '20200110' );       

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_css' );
```

It should work now! Please try with this

Comment: I have done this and it still will not work. Might it be because it is being used as a plugin?

Comment: Hi Shauna,  maybe you doing something wrong,  it working here without any issue,  please see the screenshot https://ibb.co/hD19HMb .  ,  I've made same dir structure and it working, so my last solution should work